# Clang-format not adding brace to new line

Tags: c, clang, clang-format

I'm creating a rule to always add a new line before adding brace for functions, enums stucts etc. But it's having the opposite effect of changing all my code to keeping the brace on the same line.

Expected Behavior:

```
typedef enum
{
   DATA = (1 << 0),
   STATUS = (1 << 1),
   VALUE = (1 << 2),
} TESTER;
```

Behavior observed

```
typedef enum {
   DATA = (1 << 0),
   STATUS = (1 << 1),
   VALUE = (1 << 2),
} TESTER;
```

Clang format file:

```
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
IndentCaseLabels: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
ColumnLimit: 80
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: true
  BeforeElse: false
  IndentBraces: false
```

Comment: I confirmed your example behavior with version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4, but it looks like there was a bug with "typedef enum" that should be fixed in newer versions. https://reviews.llvm.org/D37143

Comment: @jamieguinan Thanks for that. However I manually built the very latest release 5.0.1 and the issue still remains, looks like that commit wasn't included. I have went back as far as 3.8 and the issue is still there. Guess I will have to apply the commit myself and build the source. Thanks very much

Comment: The magic number seems to be 3.6. This configures the expected behavior.

Comment: Has this problem been solved? I'm using clang-format on Ubuntu16.04.3 and I got the same problem.

Comment: Yes, solved. I have Ubuntu 18.04, and it uses `clang-format` 6.0.0 and I verified the problem is solved on this version.